# How to use Solve to isolate one variable in equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I have

`x = 1 - 1/2/y^2 - 1/y/Exp[y^2]/Sqrt[Pi]`

I would like to write $y$ in terms of $x$ and I know $x$ is real. I tried

`Assuming[y > 0, Solve [x == 1 - 1/2/y^2 - 1/y/Exp[y^2]/Sqrt[Pi] , y]]`

However, this gives me an error message and asks me to use Reduce. How can I get something of the form $y = f(x)$?

Comment: `Assuming[y>0,Reduce[x==1-1/2/y^2-1/y/Exp[y^2]/Sqrt[Pi],y]]` returns "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce." Many problems have no solution in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: It's impossible. But you have to see what your goal is. If you want to plot $y(x)$, it is very simple to do. If you want to get an approximate $y(x)$ around some point $x_0$, it is also easy. If you want to compute and plot the derivative $dy/dx$, it is also possible.

Comment: If you don't mind, `f = InverseFunction[y \[Function] 1 - 1/2/y^2 - 1/y/Exp[y^2]/Sqrt[Pi]]` just do the job, then you can use `f[x]`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments - I did not think deeply before posting the question but you have all raised some good points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a symbolic approximation helps:

First transform the equation `x==1-1/2/y^2-...`  to

`y == 1/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 - x - 1/(Sqrt[Pi] y Exp[y^2])])`

Second substitute repeatedly `y` in the righthandside
(starting with `y==1/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 - x])`)

```
sol = NestList[ 1/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 - x - 1/(Sqrt[Pi] # Exp[#^2])]) &,1/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 - x]), 4];
```

Approximation sol[[4]] fit's quite well:

```
Show[{ParametricPlot[ {1 - 1/2/y^2 - 1/y/Exp[y^2]/Sqrt[Pi], y} , {y, 
    0, 5}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.01], Blue}] ,
  Plot[sol[[-1]] // Evaluate, {x, -3, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> Red]}]
```

[image]